# The Disk Drive for /tmp is not ready yet. S to skip mount or M for manual recovery

Tags: 12.04, boot, mount

I know this has been asked before, but I can't find an answer that also pertains to this /tmp message.  I have 12.04 LTS on a Toshiba laptop, as well as Windows 7. I really just started to dig into Ubuntu on here, and so I barely have anything on the system. At this point I use Ubuntu for XBMC streaming, and anything VPN related.
 For the past few months everything was fine. Last week I started to theme it with icons and borders.... that's the only thing I've done. Shortly after, I get this message regarding /tmp drive. I just wait the 5 seconds and let it boot, but I'm curious what's going on. What I could have done to make this happen now. After it boots, everything works fine.
 Everything shows healthy in G parted.
I see this question asked a dozen times, but a dozen different answers in search.  It would be great to not only fix it, but figure out how it happened.
Thanks

[image: G parted]

EDIT: I see on Ubuntu Forums someone tried `mount -o remount, rw /`  Can I try that now, or would I have to restart, press M for manual, then type command in terminal?

2ND EDIT: Here's what I get after   `cat /etc/fstab`

```
mike@Mike-Ubuntu12:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=71d51bdc-9bd4-4897-85fb-c08d68620d4b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=58a3a8ae-eb46-459c-9464-47cfa932b498 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

ALSO, I get this TMP  message sporadically. I booted my computer twice today and have not gotten this message (so I don't know if the fstab even helps) But I got the message yesterday.

Edit: `blkid`  and `fstab` in Gedit
[image: Gedit screenshot]

Comment: Add your /etc/fstab to your question.

Comment: I finally got a day to myself, and a chance to focus on this. I added /etc/fstab.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can be related to : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/1091792

You need to reboot and press M for manual to run `mount -o remount, rw /`, but I think it won't solve your problem on it's own. You should run a `fsck` on / (or /tmp if it's a separated filesystem from /).

Did you upgrade your ubuntu recently? If yes you should also try to `apt-get install -f` repair all packages. (maybe some packages from installing themes are broken)

Comment: No, I haven't upgraded. I installed 12.04 a few months ago, and stayed with it. To run " fsck " , could you explain the steps, or is it a specific code for terminal :ie / fsck (or something) Thanks

Comment: - Reboot the system

- When "The Disk Drive for /tmp is not ready yet. S to skip mount or M for manual recovery" appeares press M

- `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: And then run `apt-get install -f` first.

Comment: Ok thanks. Strange, I just restarted my computer and the message did not appear this time. It booted straight up. So, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

you need update fstab.
simple way:

1. Open terminal.(i say first terminal)
2. in terminal write `sudo blkid`.
3. every partition has an `UUID`,don't close this terminal and go to 4.
4. right click on terminal and `open Terminal` or `New Tab`.
5. in new terminal(second terminal) write `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`.fstab
   file opens.
6. the `UUID` that appears in fstab should be same `UUID` that appears
   with `sudo blkid`.if any `UUID` in fstab differs ,you should copy it
   from first terminal on fstab.
7. save and exit .
8. restart to see result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I posted a screenshot, but to me, the UUID in sda5 and sda6 match on both. I still get this message at boot up, but only sometimes. And I just wait an added 10 seconds and it boots fine.

Comment: excuse me,my answer is for ntfs drive